# Integral of multivariate probability function divided by its marginal?

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-probability

I do not know how properly establish the problem in words, I will show it in equations. 
$$ \int f_{Y|X}(y|x) dx = \int \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} dx $$ where $ f_{Y|X}(y|x) $ is conditional probability. I suppose that it should integral to marginal on conditioning on x. Is some easy way to show it integrating right side of equation? Do I think properly? If yes, is some formal name for it?